# What is the appropriate "respond_with" to put in the "update" action of a nested resource controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

And it is being accessed via js.

I have my "respond_to :html, :js" line in my controller.

However, in my update action:

```
if @permission.update_attributes(params[:permission])
  respond_with [@brand,@permission]
end
```

Tries to go to the "show" method.  When I just have:

```
@permission.update_attributes(params[:permission])
```

Then my update.js.erb is accessed appropriately.

I don't understand the deal here, can anyone help?  I feel like I should have that "respond_with" line in there, though I don't really know why if it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do:

```
def update
    @brand = ....
    @permission = ....
    @permission.update_attributes(params[:permission])
    respond_with [@brand, @permission]
end
```

[Read more here.](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering)